# php json_decode, opencart custom fields

Tags: php, json

I have this value in SQL; `{"1":"","3":"3","4":"5.11.1988"}`

want parse this by php like:

```
$json = {"1":"","3":"3","4":"5.11.1988"};  
echo $json['4']
5.11.1988
```

thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it notes that there is an optional second param to turn the decoded json object into an associative array so to be able to access your object in that manner all you need do is

```
$json = '{"1":"","3":"3","4":"5.11.1988"}';  
$decodedJson = json_decode($json, true);
echo $decodedJson[4]; // or '4' if you prefer.
// 5.11.1988
```